# Associate multiple tag groups with multiple models

Tags: mysql, laravel

So I have 3 main model tables in my Laravel project for historical data collection in may database:

- Saints
- Shrines
- Events

I want to add tags to each instance of a model to relate to properties so they can be compared. I can do this with a 'tags' table and then possibly 3 extra pivot tables (saint_tag, shrine_tag, event_tag) with the corresponding id's.

However, I wanted to group tags in each model, particularly a Shrine. So tags will be related to a specific question/ field on each model which may  consist of several groups of tags, which for a Shrine could be:

### Tag Groups

- Materials: stone, gold, silver
- Type: sculpture, hand-made
- Showing: people, adults, children, royalty, **alive**
- Saint shown in the shrine: **alive**, gesturing, sadness

This is a basic example, but as you can see, **alive** appears in two groups withing the same model and it is important to be able to distinguish which group it is in when comparing data.

I don't want to just store the tags as a string array for each field so that I'm not just comparing strings for instances. Mostly so that I can suggest tags to users inputting data from the tags table and should help with consistency.

So how would it be best to set this up in a database? With a separate column in the pivot table like 'tag_group' maybe? So `shrine_tag` could have a primary key of `[tag_id, shrine_id, tag_group]` possibly?

Also, Ideally I like to be able to scale easily, so I can add different models to the system without lots of additional tables. So would it be a good idea to have a single pivot table for all models for their tags and groups with a 4-way primary key like `[tag_id, tag_group, model_id, model_type]`. That way I can added new model types without new pivot tables? Or is that considered bad practise?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents : You're on the right track, only need a slight adjustment . You can normalize the tag_group into a separate table and reference the id from the pivot tables. In such the pivot tables now have `[tag_id, shrine_id, group_id]` and you can index the 3 columns as primary if you want to keep the group and tags unique.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, however what about when I want to add new models to the database. Should I just add new pivot tables or should I have `model_type` and `model_id` columns (so a 4-way primary, and remove `shrine_id` for example) to allow any number of tags for different models in the same table? Or should I just keep them all separate?